# Implement macros based on cyclic (sub)module dependencies

Tags: module, julia, metaprogramming

If you have two modules, `A` and `B`, which should contain two functions, `bar` and `baz`, that depend each other's module, this can be implemented by first declaring the functions as empty, and adding methods afterwards:

```
module Wrapper


module A

const x = 1

function bar end

end # module A


module B

const x = 2

function baz end

end # module B


import .A: bar
import .B: baz

bar(expr) = quote
    println("bar", $(B.x))
    $expr
end

baz(expr) = quote
    println("baz", $(A.x))
    $expr
end

end # module Wrapper
```

However, I have a case where `A` and `B` contain macros that depend on `bar` and `baz`.  Since (I think?) I cannot add methods to a macro from outside a module, they have to be declared inside. But then I cannot circumvent the cyclic imports anymore -- the following fails because `WARNING: could not import Wrapper.B into A`, leaving `B` undefined in `A`:

```
module Wrapper


module A

import ..Wrapper.B

const x = 1

macro foo(expr)
    B.baz(expr)
end

function bar end

end # module A


module B

import ..Wrapper.A

const x = 2

macro foo(expr)
    A.bar(expr)
end

function baz end

end # module B


import .A: bar
import .B: baz

bar(expr) = quote
    println("bar", $(B.x))
    $expr
end

baz(expr) = quote
    println("baz", $(A.x))
    $expr
end

end # module Wrapper
```

Is there any possibility how this pattern can be implemented?  (Just renaming the `foo`s and moving them into `Wrapper` is not really an option, since I want the names to be the same...).

Answer (score 0):

I could solve the problem by declaring `bar` and `baz` outside of `A` and `B`, using and redefining them in the submodules, and finally implementing their methods afterwards:

```
module Wrapper

function bar end
function baz end


module A

import ..Wrapper

const x = 1

macro foo(expr)
    Wrapper.baz(expr)
end

const bar = Wrapper.bar

end # module A


module B

import ..Wrapper

const x = 2

macro foo(expr)
    Wrapper.bar(expr)
end

const baz = Wrapper.baz

end # module B


import .A
import .B

bar(expr) = quote
    println("bar", $(B.x))
    $expr
end

baz(expr) = quote
    println("baz", $(A.x))
    $expr
end

end # module Wrapper
```

Result:

```
julia> Wrapper.A.bar(1)
quote
    #= /tmp/test.jl:119 =#
    println("bar", 2)
    #= /tmp/test.jl:120 =#
    1
end

julia> Wrapper.B.baz(1)
quote
    #= /tmp/test.jl:124 =#
    println("baz", 1)
    #= /tmp/test.jl:125 =#
    1
end

julia> Wrapper.B.@foo 1
bar2
1

julia> Wrapper.A.@foo 1
baz1
1
```